# Update-MgDevice - issue with changing accountEnabled status

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to disable devices using Update-MgDevice. According to the documentation, -AccountEnabled should be a switch that accepts a boolean (true or false)

I can get the accountEnabled property status, whether true or false, using Get-MgDevice, but I can't seem to enable or disable using Update-MgDevice

Whether or not I use Update-MgDevice -AccountEnabled $True/'true'true or use Update-MgDevice -AccountEnabled $False/'false'/false I get the same error:

Update-MgDevice : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'.
or
Update-MgDevice : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'False'.

Am I just not understanding the switch properly?

Comment: Have you tried AccountEnabled:$false?

Comment: Good tip, @bluuf. iBowler, [`Update-MgDevice`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/update-mgdevice?view=graph-powershell-beta)'s `-AccountEnabled` parameter is a _switch_ parameter, which means that _normally_ `-AccountEnabled` alone _implies_ `$true` and the _absence_ of the parameter implies `$false`.  To pass a value _explicitly_ - which `Update-MgDevice` seemingly - and unfortunately  - requires if you want to pass `$false` - you _must_ follow the parameter name with `:`, i.e. `-AccountEnabled: $false`. See the linked duplicate.